# Select Tab name to show in browser's URL

Tags: urls, tabs

I'm a front-end developer and currently working on a wordpress site. 
The site have a Tabbed section on one of the page, clicking on any tab load the relevant div (as expected). What I want is, when any Tab is clicked/selected, it's name should show up in the browser's URL bar.
Please guide me in this, thanks.

- M. Jawaid

Comment: That’s not what the address bar is for. The address bar shows the URL. What would changing it to something else achieve?

Comment: It's needed for SEO purposes, just to show the selected menu name.

Comment: A search engine isn’t going to pick up on it. I don’t understand why this is necessary. I’ve never even see it before. You know when you add a page in WordPress then the page name is part of the URL already, right?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, the page name is part of the URL, but I don't need the page name, I need the selected Tab name on any page to show up with the URL.

Comment: Sorry but *Why?*. You mentioned SEO, but Google's bots don't *have* an address bar, so they're not gonna care what you do to it. And as a user I'd be *so* annoyed if this happened. It's essentially breaking the browser for no reason. You're not talking about the title bar or the browser tabs are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something I would suggest and not sure why you want that. But using hashes you can do

```
    $('#action_tab').click(function () {
      window.location.hash = 'xyz';
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, It's for marketing purposes, let me try this solution.